# Registration page is missing in a BuddyPress website

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am a newbie to word press and buddy press.For learning purpose I have created an account in a free word press hosting site and installed buddy press manually.But in my buddy press website when I am clicking on register new user link its showing a "Page not found" error message.

I have checked the buddy press folder and found a registration folder inside it.Can anyone please suggest a solution for this problem. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

> a free word press hosting site....

That's the problem. Free hosting sites are crippled and typically don't allow mod_rewrite and have other reduced functions that will impact anything more than a bare-bones WP install. Get a real hosting account: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I just want to learn word press and buddy press,that's why I chose free hosting. Any way I will try other real hosting.

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to you if the free host problem was actually the problem but the way to create a custom registration page is as follows..

1. In wordpress create a new page. **Name it** anything you like, let's say 'Register' and then click **Publish** Don't alter it in any other way.
2. A. In the wordpress admin panel go to **settings -> buddypress -> pages**.

   B. Under **Registration -> Register** choose 'Register' (this is the blank page you created of the same name.)
3. Get a copy of register.php from bp-legacy (the default BP templates location)

   /wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/register.php
4. Rename it to index-register.php and copy it to this location..

   /wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/buddypress/members/index-register.php
5. Your registration page will be at your.website/register/ Check that it is working (and of course change your.website to your actual domain name)

   - If you've followed these steps properly you will know wether your host is the problem.
   - You can customize index-register.php to suit your needs.